# Including js/css files with yarn 3.5

Tags: yarnpkg

I have started a new project using Yarn 3 (am familiar with yarn 1). I have added project dependencies using `yarn add` (bootstrap, jquery etc., which have been added to package.json), but i don't quite understand how to include these files in my project.

In yarn1 there was a node_modules / assets folder, which was in the web root and simply linked to using link / script tags. I understand Yarn2 has now deprecated the node_modules directory approach and is favouring Plug'n'Play - but where exactly are the files to be used locally in my project stored?
How do i include them in my web page?

I have looked through the documentation, which states setting `nodeLinker: node-modules` in .yarnrc.yml will install the node_modules folder, but this is the approach that yarn is trying to step away from - how do you include files that are loaded via pnp?

Is it also possible to rename and relocate node_modules? Default installation path is not in web root, i'd prefer it in public/node_modules, or preferably public/assets so i don't need to change any existing filepaths throughout the source code.

Using Yarn 3.5.1